# Duplicity can only restore as root on OS X

Tags: macos, backup, permissions, duplicity

When I try to list or restore files from my duplicity backup in S3 on my OS X machine, I run into a permissions error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/duplicity", line 1411, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/local/bin/duplicity", line 1404, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/local/bin/duplicity", line 1282, in main
    sync_archive(decrypt)
  File "/usr/local/bin/duplicity", line 1082, in sync_archive
    copy_to_local(fn)
  File "/usr/local/bin/duplicity", line 1031, in copy_to_local
    tdp.move(globals.archive_dir.append(loc_name))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/duplicity/path.py", line 618, in move
    self.copy(new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/duplicity/path.py", line 444, in copy
    self.copy_attribs(other)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/duplicity/path.py", line 449, in copy_attribs
    util.maybe_ignore_errors(lambda: os.chown(other.name, self.stat.st_uid, self.stat.st_gid))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/duplicity/util.py", line 65, in maybe_ignore_errors
    return fn()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/duplicity/path.py", line 449, in <lambda>
    util.maybe_ignore_errors(lambda: os.chown(other.name, self.stat.st_uid, self.stat.st_gid))
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/dlp/.cache/duplicity/duply_default/duplicity-full-signatures.20130611T011527Z.sigtar.gz'
```

The permissions on the file in question are 600, and I am the owner:

```
$ ls -alh ~/.cache/duplicity/duply_default/duplicity-full-signatures.20130611T011527Z.sigtar.gz 
-rw-------  1 dlp  staff    11M Jun 11 15:31 /Users/dlp/.cache/duplicity/duply_default/duplicity-full-signatures.20130611T011527Z.sigtar.gz
```

If I run duplicity as root, I can list files as expected. The files were originally backed up on a VPS running Debian 7. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 5):

This should fix your problem:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.cache/tmp
$ duplicity <your options> --tempdir=~/.cache/tmp
```

More informations about this bug (and a second workaround that didn't work for me):
https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/1077647